# Paypal not processing create order

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to have PayPal process an order using checkout rest api. using c#. I have an order which shows on PayPal checkout page. Neither PP or CC finish processing. PP loops back from review order to Order Page, CC hangs up. My Order is

```
{
   "intent":"CAPTURE",
   "payer":{
      "email":"xxx@isongu.com"
   },
   "purchase_units":[
      {
         "reference_id":"A-ISU-20231017-125939-0-130-0",
         "description":"ISU Mystery Song-Est.Taxes & Fees Included",
         "amount":{
            "currency_code":"USD",
            "value":"1.00"
         },
         "payee":{
            "email":"zzz@isongu.com"
         }
      }
   ],
   "payment_source":{
      "paypal":{
         "email_address":"xxx@isongu.com"
      },
      "experience_content":{
         "payment_method_preference":"IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED",
         "brand_name":"ISU",
         "locale":"en-US",
         "landing_page":"LOGIN",
         "user_action":"PAY_NOW",
         "return_url":"http://localhost:50838/Account/isu-review-thanks.aspx",
         "cancel_url":"http://localhost:50838/Account/isu-review-cancel.aspx"
      }
   }
}
```

I am using `client.UploadString(paypal_path2, "POST", orderJson);` and I can see the data from client.DownloadString(paypal_path2);. Any ideas? Thank you in advanced.

Would like PP to process the order and return to my thank you or cancel page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided you are likely missing the approve and/or capture steps (both are required).

For approval, you can [use the JS SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/). This will render JS+HTML buttons that, when clicked, will call your backend to retrieve the JSON response of a created order, in particular an object with its `id` value. This is then used to open an in context PayPal checkout.

Alternatively, you can redirect away from your website. This is an old integration pattern used by old ecommerce software. You should not implement it (use the JS SDK instead, so that no redirect away from your website is required).

After an order has been approved, the final step is to capture it, using the corresponding v2/checkout/orders API call. A JS SDK integration will call your backend to initiate this last step from its `onApprove` callback function.

Once you do the capture API operation, you should display a clear success or failure message to the payer based on the API response.